# A Complicated has_many through Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through

I am going back and forth between three different ways to implement a `has_many` through relationship and I need some help deciding which is best.

At a basic level I have `Contributor` models which holds an individual's details, and I have a `Project` model to which the contributors can contribute. They can contribute in a number of different ways; a `Contributor` can be an editor, an author, a composer, a researcher etc. A Contributor can contribute in multiple ways to the same `Project` (for example they can be a composer and an editor), and they can contribute to multiple `Projects`.

So I've set up a join model called `Contributorship`. My question is what to do next. As far as I can see I have three options:

1. Add a `contribution_type` attribute to `Contributorship` that holds the type of contribution (from a predefined enumeration). When I set up a relationship between `Contributor` and `Project` I set this the the appropriate value.
2. Create multiple `has_many through` relationships on `Project`, one for each type of contribution. Each one still resolves to a `Contributor`, but uses a different foreign key on `Contributorship`.
3. Ditch `Contributorship` and replace it with multiple join models - `Editor`, `Author` etc. which all resolve to `Contributors`.

Comment: is polymorphic for Contributor can be usable in your case? it can simplify some of yours relationships. later you can manage access with cancan easily for polymorphic associations too where Contributor is just a Role

Comment: @okliv The problem is that a `Contributor` can be an author for one project and an editor for another, or both composer and editor for another. In all cases the `Contributor` is the same, so I can't use different (polymorphic) `Contributor` types. The type of Contribution must be separate from the `Contributor`.

Comment: may i operate with generic models )? then you have this case: `User=>UserRoleProject<=Project` and `Role=>UserRoleProject`.. is it? (where `=>`  is `has_many` direction)

Comment: @okliv There is no `Role`. Just Contributor=>Contributorship<=Project, with `Contributorship` representing the type of contribution a contributor makes to the project (author, editor, composer etc).

Comment: you have `type of contribution` - Editor, Author... i named them Role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the first option. Additionally I would define methods on project for easy access.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ... relations defined
  Contributorship::TYPES.each do |c_type|
    define_method c_type do
      contributors.where( "contributorship.contribution_type" => c_type )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 sounds clean and simple. It also allows you to fetch all the contributors regardless of type in one query. And you can always create finder methods on Project to fetch only editors or authors. It also allows to add contribution_types very easy.

Option 2 and 3 will work but are more rigid than the first option. They also require more tables and model classes to be created.

My advice: go for the simplest of solutions that will work now and wait until there are new requirements that require more complicated relations.

Answer (score 1):

Are you afraid of `ContributionType` model?

Definitely first option but i would associate three models: `Project`, `Contributor` and `ContributionType` (new one, instead of enumeration) all through `Contributorship` model.

This gives you nearest representation of the reality and eventually gives generic freedom in any future moves (models complication, authorization and so on).